# Why does "bash -c 'echo $hiveURI" show a value while "ssh host 'bash -c echo $hiveURI'" shows nothing?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have a program that works when run on the host, but fails when running via ssh because an environment variable is not being set.

This variable is being set in `/etc/environment` as `export hiveURI=connectstring`.

All of the following return `connectstring`:

```
echo $hiveURI
bash -c 'echo $hiveURI'
sh -c 'echo $hiveURI'
ssh host 'echo $hiveURI'
```

But the following commands return null:

```
ssh host 'bash -c echo $hiveURI'
ssh host 'sh -c echo $hiveURI'
```

I have no control over how the program is being called remotely, but I suspect it's one of the last two.

What's happening and how do I fix it?

Update:

As mentioned below, I should have used more quotes. The last two commands, quoted properly, return `connectstring`. So, this question has been answered, but my problem remains. Thank you for your input.

Comment: `bash -c echo $hiveURI` will never work; it needs more quotes. It's treating `echo` as a script to run with whatever `hiveURI` expands to passed as arguments to that script... but the script `echo` _never reads its arguments at all_, so even if the value is there, it gets ignored.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with `ssh host env`, to make sure the variable is truly set on the remote system.

Comment: If that works, the next place to start would be `ssh host $'bash -c \'echo $hiveURI\''`

Comment: though there's no reason to use the `bash -c`  at all: `ssh host somecommand arg1 arg2 ...` _always_ implicitly starts `sh -c 'somecommand arg1 arg2 ...'` over on `host`.

Comment: ...so `ssh host 'bash -c echo $hiveURI'` is, on the remote host, starting (in JSON syntax) `["sh", "-c", "bash -c echo $hiveURI"]`. `bash -c echo $hiveURI` will fail the same way if you run it locally without ssh, btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-c` option to `bash` only takes one argument. So

```
bash -c echo $hiveURI
```

is only using `echo` as the argument to `-c`, not `echo $hiveURI`. You need to put it into quotes to include the variable in the command, just like you did when you ran `bash -c 'echo $hiveURI'` on the host directly.

```
ssh host 'bash -c "echo $hiveURI"'
```

Comment: Mind, since `ssh host` implicitly runs `sh -c` with the concatenation of other arguments passed to it, `sh -c 'bash -c "..."'` is darned silly (when not using bash-only syntax or utilities).

Comment: True, that's why `ssh host 'echo $hiveURI'` works. There may be cases where you need to use `bash -c` explicitly, perhaps after setting some other variables on the remove server. `ssh host 'var=$(something); bash -c "$var something else"'`